# How to pass the parameters to service from an activity?

Tags: android

Hey , i am starting a service from a activity. I am calling the service from activity by `startService();`. But i want some variables from my activity to use in the services code which i am invoking in my activity, So please tell me how to do that?

Is there a way to pass the parameters to service from calling activity?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can add a [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to your intent (as an 'extra').
You can put all sorts of stuff (string, ints, bools, etc) in a bundle, and get them out later.