# Android MediaPlayer stops on backpressed

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, back, onbackpressed

I'm  developing a radio stream app.I use android - mediaplayer class which plays radiostream. I m trying to run app in two devices . When I pressed back button in Samsung galaxy S3 mini(4.2.2) radio stream continues to playing. And I controls media player with notification bar. But when I pressed back button in Samsung galaxy S3(4.3) mediaplayer stopping to play. Why is stopping media player? How can I prevent stop when pressed back?

Comment: Is this a programming question or a device support question?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry there is a misunderstanding . My explain is some missing . I m developing a radio stream app. The mediaplayer is android mediaplayer. I use android mediaplayer in my code.I updated.

Comment: so You should show what You have done in code....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs but there is no exception. Only I pressed back button . There is only    super.onBackPressed();

Comment: look here, some possible solutions... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668298/how-do-android-mediaplayers-continuing-playing-songs-when-app-is-closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use service but still I have not understood why s3 kills activity. But I found a solution . I change my super.onBackPressed()  to moveTaskToBack(true);. And I added this option to manifest file in activity tag(Main)  android:noHistory="true". Anymore when I pressed back key MediaPlayer isn't stopping stream. Maybe this solution may be useful to someone else. And I thanks for all of you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Without some code i doubt anyone will be able to help.

How are you playing the radio stream? Are you using a service? If not the back button on S3 could be killing your app thus terminating the stream.